# How to pull a particular text after <span> tag text in HTML with Python

Tags: python, html

In the following HTML example, how can I pull a text ($167.00 in this case) after the span tag "Price Target (6-12 Months):" in Python?  My crude attempt below that I tried copying from some posts without any prior knowledge in Python didn't work.  Thank you for any solution!

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

HTML = '''
<tr>
<td class="company_name alpha">
<h1> Apple Inc. (AAPL) </h1>
<p>$148.19
<span>(As of 08/20/21)</span>
</p>
<p>
<span>Price Target (6-12 Months):</span>
$167.00
</p>
</td>
</tr>
'''

page = requests.get(HTML)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
value = soup.find('span', text=re.compile("Price Target”).find_next('span').text
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you were close, but the weird html wasn't helping you

```
# you can't access the price directly, get the parent
p_contents = soup.find('span', text=re.compile("Price Target")).parent.contents

# you could now access the price with p_contents[2].strip()
# but it's better to check if you're really matching a price
for value in p_contents:
    res = re.match('\$\d{0,5}\.\d{2}', value.strip())
    if res:
        print(res[0])
```