# How to pull text after a specific span tag text but having sup tag in HTML with Python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I used to pull text after a specific span tag, based on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68868468/how-to-pull-a-particular-text-after-span-tag-text-in-html-with-python).  In the example, the code retrieved $167.00 from the old HTML, which is Price Target and what I want.   But since the website format was changed to the New HTML below, the code returns nothing with the New HTML. The span tag of `<span>Price Target (6-12 Months):</span>` is changed to `<span>Price Target (6-12 Months)<sup>(2)</sup>:</span>`

Old HTML:

> ## Apple Inc. (AAPL)
>
> $148.19
> (As of 08/20/21)
>
> Price Target (6-12 Months):
> $167.00

New HTML:

> ## Apple Inc. (AAPL)
>
> $148.19
> (As of 08/20/21)
>
> Price Target (6-12 Months)<sup>(2)</sup>:
> $167.00

What should be changed in the code below, in order to retrieve $167.00?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import re

HTML = '''
<h1> Apple Inc. (AAPL) </h1>
<p>$148.19
<span>(As of 08/20/21)</span>
</p>
<p>
<span>Price Target (6-12 Months)<sup>(2)</sup>:</span>
$167.00
</p>
'''

page = requests.get(HTML)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'lxml')
value = soup.find('span', string=re.compile("Price Target")).parent.contents[1]
print(value)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can search for `<span>` tag containing the text `"Price Target"` and then next text sibling:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

HTML = '''
<h1> Apple Inc. (AAPL) </h1>
<p>$148.19
<span>(As of 08/20/21)</span>
</p>
<p>
<span>Price Target (6-12 Months)<sup>(2)</sup>:</span>
$167.00
</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML, 'lxml')

value = soup.select_one('span:-soup-contains("Price Target")').find_next_sibling(string=True).strip()
print(value)
```

Prints:

```
$167.00
```